# Activity doesn't return from Pause

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app with three activities: splashscreen (default), login, main. The application starts with splash, after some seconds changes to login. If the login process is correct then we go to main.

My problem is the login activity cannot be recovered from a paused state. When I hit the Home button the onPause() is called correctly and onDestroy() is not called. Then when trying to return to the application, it starts on splash but never reaches login, it just goes back to Home. The logcat doesn't show any error and the debugger states the application is still open (like it should). The behavior on the splash and main screens is the expected.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
/* UI ELEMENTS */
private OnClickListener mOnClickListener;

private EditText mPasswordField;

private EditText mUserField;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

/* LOGIC ELEMENTS */
/** handler to update interface */
private static Handler sInterfaceUpdateHandler;


public static class UpdateHandler extends Handler {

    private final WeakReference<LoginActivity> mLogin;

    UpdateHandler(final LoginActivity loginActivity) {
        super();
        mLogin = new WeakReference<LoginActivity>(loginActivity);
    }

    /**
     * handle events from other threads in UI thread.
     * 
     * @param message message data. Property what determines action.
     */
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message message) {
       // STUFF HERE
    }


@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.initializeInterface(); // fields filled here, listener added to buttons
}
```

EDIT: Activity creation in SplashScreen as per request

```
 public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    final Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while (waited < 2000) {
                    sleep(100);
                    waited += 100;
                }
            } catch (final InterruptedException catchException) {
                LoggerFactory.consoleLogger().printStackTrace(catchException);
            }
            SplashScreen.this.finish();
            final Intent loginIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
            SplashScreen.this.startActivity(loginIntent);
        }
    };
    splashThread.start();
}
```

}

Comment: I think you need to call finish() before startActicity call for LoginScreen

Comment: Your code is not relevant to the problem you describe. How does your splash load the login activity?

Comment: final Intent loginIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    SplashScreen.this.startActivity(loginIntent);

Comment: the code you provided don't help at all, and doesn't have anything to do with the "problem" you describes.  you need to post the LoginActivity code, and SplashScreen

Comment: Splashscreen code is there, what part of login you want? Because it's 500 lines of business code I'm not willing to share :)

Comment: I added some more code with indications, but it's useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error found and fixed. The activity was marked as SingleInstance in the manifest. I changed it to SingleTop and now it works as expected.

More documentation on the cause can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: Add launchMode to which activity? Main? or Login?

Comment: All of them, try to avoid SingleInstance as its a very very edge type of activity that doesn't fit most apps. In the past year and a half I've wised up about never using it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the finally block from your `SplashActivity` and as below :

> ```
> final Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
>     @Override
>     public void run() {
>         try {
>             int waited = 0;
>             while (waited < 2000) {
>                 sleep(100);
>                 waited += 100;
>             }
>         } catch (final InterruptedException catchException) {
>             LoggerFactory.consoleLogger().printStackTrace(catchException);
>         } 
>             SplashScreen.this.finish();
>             final Intent loginIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
>             SplashScreen.this.startActivity(loginIntent);
>         }
> };
> splashThread.start();
> ```

Comment: Which part do you need? I cannot post it whole.

Comment: Post that in which find issue , `onBackPressed()` also.

Comment: There's not a "part with an issue". Hit Home (not Back, Home), back to the desktop, try to return, the app restarts. Methods passes through during that: onPause, already documented atop. onKeyDown() is just a call to super.onKeyDown() but it's not being called.

Comment: Are you calling `finish()` anywhere in your `LoginActivity`? You are asking for help with code that you have written, but then saying you cannot show us the code, this makes it quite difficult to debug. Consider this: You have all the information and are unable to debug on your own, yet you want to give us half of that information and expect us to figure out your problem... I think minimum you should post your `onCreate()`, `onPause()`, and `onResume()`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with threading much but from what it looks like to me, you are creating another thread from the Splash Activity and then starting an activity from that thread. Then when you go to pause, your new activity is somehow getting lost or garbage collected (maybe because it is not on the main thread i dont know) then when you return to the previous activity, onCreate is not called again, thus you have this perpetual SplashScreen (if I'm understanding your problem right).

Edit also I have to ask why you are waiting inside that thread?

Comment: It's a splash screen, the logic is just showing an image and after X seconds, start the new screen. The code is not mine, it was taken from a SO answer.

Comment: Also, the problem is not that the splash doesn't dissappear. It does, it just doesn't load the LoginActivity afterwards.